# D3.js table appending same data values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, d3.js

I'm trying to programmatically 'add' rows to a table that I've created using d3.

```
        @appendLine line for line in arr
appendSingleColLine:(line)->
        newModel = new PhoenixModel()
        newModel.set({logLine : line})

        view = new RowView({model:newModel})
        view.render()
class RowView extends Backbone.View
    el : "tr"
    row : {}
    columns : {}
    line : {}
    tbody : {}

    render:()->
        #console.log "in render"
        @line = @options.model.get("logLine")
        @columns = @options.columns
        @tbody = @options.tbody
        @row = @tbody.selectAll('tr').data(@line).enter().append("tr")
        console.log "checking row"
        console.log @line
        console.log @row
        @row.selectAll("td").data(@line).enter().append("td").text((d)-> 
            return d
        )
```

The result of this is that the first data get's entered three times. When I look at @row, the entries into the array are all null, which is why I think my problem is occuring. However, I don't know why this is happening, as to my mind I'm binding new data.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell what exactly is going on here. A jsfiddle could help. My guess is that the problem is with the way you're binding the data. You're building a table, which means binding two-dimensional data, which is kind of a special case.

Have a look at the table example here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data.
Note how the 2nd `data()` binding needs to use a function. That may well be the issue.

Unrelated to d3 or your issue, but just for style: `@options.model` can just be replaced with `@model`, which Backbone automatically sets for you.